# Is there a good reason we should not always use Google API SDK?

Tags: android

So far, I used the regular SDK in most projects, and used Google API SDK only when the project will utilize some of Google's feature.

I am now wondering is there a good reason I should NOT always use Google API SDK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are devices without Google services installed. In this case the Google API is not available. By not using the Google API SDK, your app can still run on these devices.

E.g. consider the Kindle Fire, it doesn’t have the Play store installed, as well as various low-budget tablets and Chinese phones. Custom builds from the open-source code such as Cyanogenmod also don’t have the Google apps installed (although many users add them manually).

Although Android itself is open-source, the Google apps require the vendor to get a license from Google. I know this because custom builds were asked by Google to not include their apps. Also having their own store instead of the Play Store is attractive for some manufacturers because then they get a share of the revenue instead of letting Google have all the profits. This is why not all devices have them.

Comment: Yes, Kindle Fire may be a good reason! But then again, I have never seen a reverse advise like "use google api all the time, but take care of XY situations when you cannot use it". Even Google developers team does not advise to use Google API SDK more often than the regular one.

Comment: I guess another factor may be that it probably adds some bloat to your binary that can be avoided if you don’t use it.

Comment: Good observation on devices without Google apps. I did not know about the licence, but then again, it's so logical :). Also I have never seen cheap Chinese devices without Play Store app. Maybe I was not using the bottom level devices so far.

Comment: Bloat = increased size? Or something else?

Comment: Yeah, indeed. Probably not by much though if you compact the binary with Proguard.

Comment: @sandalone Also note that Google Play is banned in China, so all Android devices sold in China do not have any Google services installed. This is part of the reason why there are literately well over 100 Chinese Android app stores.

Answer (score 1):

One potential reason is this: why should you include something if you aren't using it? When you write a new class, do you `import` the entirety of the Android framework? No, you wouldn't, because at worst it could cause problems in your code, and even in the best case it takes up extra space in your resulting APK.

I'm not sure how much additional space would be taken up in memory/storage by building your app using the Google API SDK, but I can't imagine it's 0, and in mobile development you can't really afford not to be judicious with resource usage.

Comment: I reckon optimising your binary with Proguard should alleviate most of the concerns in this regard though.

Comment: It may alleviate resource usage issues, but it only further worsens the complexity issue. It's another thing that (theoretically) could break, on top of the thing you've added which also could break, and didn't give you any benefit.